# i want to display only selected year data in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

Here i put my code file so you can get idea about my code

In my index.html

```
{% load tag %}

<body>

<select name="select_year">
<option>2017</option>
<option>2018</option>
<option>2019</option>
<option>2020</option>
</select>
</br>
</br>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>DOB</td>
        <td>Year</td>
    </tr>

    {% for Manvi_User in ordering %}

    <tr>
        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td>{{ Manvi_User.first_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ Manvi_User.dob}}</td>
        <td>{{year|calculate_year:forloop.counter0}}</td>
    </tr>


    {% endfor %}
</table>

</body>
```

in vies.py

```
def index(request):
    all_user = Manvi_User.objects.all()
    ordering = all_user.order_by('dob')

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'ordering': ordering})
```

in tag.py

```
@register.filter
def calculate_year(year, loop_counter):
    try:
        year = int(2017)
    except ValueError:
        return None
    else:
        return str(year + (loop_counter // 2))
```

in year i put static year using tag.py

if user select 2019 i want to display only data who have year 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand what you're trying to do here, which is to filter the queryset depending on the year selected - the way you started is not really the way to do it.

You should look into [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/) app which makes it pretty easy to accomplish what you're trying here.

For this specific situation, you'd have to define your [custom filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#the-filter) within `filters.py`, and then use that filter in your [view](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#the-view).

Comment: But here in my table the Year is static. It's not come form database

Comment: That's ok - you can use a form with the years dropdown and submit that form to the same `index` view which would look like something like this: 
`def index(request, *args, **kwargs):`
  `your_filter = YourFilter(request.GET)`
  `ordering = your_filter.qs`
  `return render(request, 'index.html', {'ordering': ordering})`